# (C#) Web Service doesn't recognize Oracle Library

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I'm currently creating a Web Service to call on my ASP/C# application, which has a basic SQL SELECT query from an Oracle Database.

The problem is that the Web Service file itself doesn't recognize the Oracle libraries, so I can't use any commands like OracleConnection and such, as they asked me to do so for work.

The commands itself work perfectly on C# pages, and have no issue at all. The Web Service can read SQL Commands like SqlConnect, but not OracleConnect.

Any way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you put the Oracle assemblies on that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing all same issue
so i upload the all assemble to server it resolve my problem also please check the all the references

then clean the solution and rebuild solution.

> **Please check the oracle version and reference dll version**

Comment: Hope it will work for you...